# I want to to scroll my whole division to 1400px in a webpage but its not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

As you can see, this is the HTML code for my container. I want to scroll this part but it's not working.

```js
// This is the javascript for the slider function

function slideRight() {
  var serviceCatalogue = document.getElementById('scroller');
  serviceCatalogue.scrollLeft = 1400
}
```

```css
/* And this is the CSS for the conatiner. */

.conatiner {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1000000000px;
  /* overflow: scroll; */
  height: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="conatiner" id="scroller">
  <i style=" position:absolute; right: 50px; margin-top: 100px;" class="fas fa-arrow-right">
    </i>
  <button id="left-button" swipe left </button>
  <button id="right-button"> swipe right </button>
</div>
```

Comment: The question needs details/clarity. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: there is a missing > in <button id="left-button" swipe left </button>

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your `.conatiner` does not have enough elements to overflow it

for example in the code below the `#conatiner` has `#content` that is bigger than the width of the parrent
#content has 500px
#conatiner has 400px

and it works just fine

```js
const button = document.getElementById('slide');

button.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft = 20;
};
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#content {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">Click the button to slide right!</div>

  <button id="slide" type="button">Slide right</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i did but it's still not working my content code is .content{
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 270px;
    left: 100px;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    border: 1px solid black;
}

Comment: @Prashantswami you seem to be confused about 2 things. FIrst when you say .conatiner {width: 1000000000px;} you are overflowing the body element. so the scroll bar that you see is for body or the parent element of .container in otherwords this scroll bar does not belong to .container hence you can not scroll it. The 2nd thing you are confused about is inorder for .container to overflow it has to have enough element widths inside that is more than .container so when you say .content{width: 270px;} is not enough because .container is 1000000px and one more thing position aboslution will not work

Comment: can you help me with this, i want to add slider to whole container,like if i click ,the div would shift to left and next three will come. i want perform this.

Comment: @Prashantswami i dont exactly understand what you want. if you need a slider (carousel) there are hundreds of free code for it  online.